# jsonconvert DeserializeObject not working

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) in order to get a model fit to the json structure.

```
  public class S
{
    public int k { get; set; }
    public string n { get; set; }
}

public class IOt
{
    public int v { get; set; }
    public S s { get; set; }
    public string tn { get; set; }
}

public class S2
{
    public int k { get; set; }
    public string n { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int k { get; set; }
    public string n { get; set; }
}

public class O
{
    public List<string> ah { get; set; }
    public List<string> ou { get; set; }
    public List<string> odd12 { get; set; }
    public List<string> ah1st { get; set; }
    public List<string> ou1st { get; set; }
    public List<string> odd121st { get; set; }
}

public class Pci
{
    public int ctid { get; set; }
    public int? pid { get; set; }
    public string ctn { get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    public bool dbg { get; set; }
    public int egid { get; set; }
    public string g { get; set; }
    public List<object> i { get; set; }
    public bool ibs { get; set; }
    public bool ibsc { get; set; }
    public int k { get; set; }
    public object no { get; set; }
    public O o { get; set; }
    public object po { get; set; }
    public Pci pci { get; set; }
    public object pvdr { get; set; }
    public string egn { get; set; }
}

public class Eg
{
    public C c { get; set; }
    public List<E> es { get; set; }
}

public class NOt
{
    public int v { get; set; }
    public S2 s { get; set; }
    public List<Eg> egs { get; set; }
    public string tn { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int tp { get; set; }
    public IOt iot { get; set; }
    public NOt not { get; set; }
}
```

then make a call

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\json.txt");
        var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

The data is always null for all objects. Am I doing anything wrong ?

The whole [json.txt you can find at my onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6A66588CF58E36FF!60403&authkey=!ALXPXExlOeQBZQY&ithint=file%2Ctxt)

Comment: Seems Like you are missing some `JsonProperty` attributes. For ex, its name in json is `i-ot`, not `iot` as in `RootObject`

Comment: never mind, the content of the json has some invalid names like 1x2 so i had to change the variable 1x2=> odd12... so it doesn't fit the name. Thanks all